# Rules of inferences problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I have an exercise that I have to prove the validity of the following arguments using rules of inference. But there is an exercise I have no idea how to prove it at all.

Problem shows as below.

1. $P\to Q$
2. $\neg P\to R$
3. $S\to \neg R$
4. $S\to \neg Q$

Conclusion $S\to T$

The exercises I have practiced before have at least one premise. However, in this exercise, it seems that no premise can be used directly. So I have no idea how to prove it by rules of inference. Can anybody give me some hints? Thanks.

PS. The following is detail of the exercise before replacing sentences with notations.

"If Superman were able to prevent evil, he would do so."

"If Superman were unable to prevent evil, he would be impotent."

"If Superman exists, he is not impotent."

"If Superman exists, he does not prevent evil."

Therefore

"If Superman exists, it is impossible to learn logic."

Comment: What does S -> T mean? S is true?

Comment: S->T means If S is true, we can imply T is true.

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.com/S5qEVGEa) might give you some tips. Generated by inputting `( p => q ) & ( -p => r ) & ( s => -r ) & ( s => -q ) => ( s => t )` [here](http://teachinglogic.liglab.fr/DN/index.php).

Answer (score 0):

First let's simplify
$$(p\to q)\land(\neg p\to r)\land(s\to\neg r)\land(s\to\neg q)$$
$$\equiv(p\to q)\land(\neg p\to r)\land(r\to\neg s)\land(q\to\neg s)$$
$$\equiv(p\to \neg s)\land(\neg p\to\neg s)$$
$$\equiv(\neg p\lor \neg s)\land(p\lor\neg s)$$
$$\equiv(\neg s\lor\neg s)$$
$$\equiv\neg s$$
So now we have
$$\neg s\to(s\to l)$$
$$\equiv s\lor\neg s\lor l$$
$$\equiv\mbox{tautology}$$